# Is it considered normal that under FE_DOWNWARD or FE_TOWARDZERO expression FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX evaluates to FLT_MAX?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754, c11

Sample code:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(void)
{
    if (fesetround(RM) != 0) return 2;
    return ((FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX) == FLT_MAX) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ clang t788.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DRM=FE_DOWNWARD && ./a.exe
<exit status 0>

$ clang t788.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DRM=FE_TOWARDZERO && ./a.exe
<exit status 0>
```

It is a bit surprising that under `FE_DOWNWARD` or `FE_TOWARDZERO` expression `FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX` evaluates to `FLT_MAX`. Is it considered normal?

Comment: Yes. IEEE-754 (2008) 7.4 Overflow: "b) roundTowardZero carries all overflows to the format’s largest finite number with the sign of the intermediate result. c) roundTowardNegative carries positive overflows to the format’s largest finite number, and carries negative overflows to −∞."

Comment: What should it round to? If you are implementing interval arithmetic and multiply the interval [a, b] by the interval [c, d], given 0 < a, b, c, d, you would compute l = `a*c` rounded down and u = `b*d` rounded up to get the interval [l, u]. If `FLT_MAX*FLT_MAX` yielded ∞, that would produce [`FLT_MAX`, ∞] • [`FLT_MAX`, ∞] → [∞, ∞], which is wrong. (For interval arithmetic, we always want the computed interval to be a superset of the possible real-number-arithmetic results.)

Comment: Sure! `FLT_MAX * FLT_MAX` is still very, very far below the half-way between `FLT_MAX` and infinity, so the rounding is correct! :)